# data normalization in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am unable to normalize data in tensorflow which is resulting in `np.nan` and `np.inf` in the losses which breaks the training.

My images are in the range `[-1, +1]`. I want to compute a binary cross entropy loss

```
_bce = -1 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(img1_n, img2_n)) + tf.mul((1 - img1_n),tf.log(1 - img2_n)), 0)

bce_loss = tf.reduce_mean(_bce)
```

Before computing the loss, I normalize the images as:

```
img1_n = (img1 + 1)/2 - 1e-8 #to prevent NaN and inf
img2_n = np.flip(img1_n)
```

This is so that the `tf.log()` takes in values from `(0,1)` not inclusive. 
I catch errors this way:

```
if np.isnan(bce_loss) or np.isinf(bce_loss):
    foo = (img1 + 1)/2 - 1e-8                          
    goo = (img1 + 1)/2 
    hoo = ((1 - 2 * 1e-8) * g + 1 - 2 * 1e-8)/2 # scaled to get [0 + 1e-8, 1 - 1e-8] ~= (0, 1)                           
    print np.min(img1), np.max(img1) #img1 ~ [-1, 1]        # -0.998874 1.0
    print np.min(img1_n), np.max(img1_n) #img1_n ~ (0, 1)   # 0.000563224 1.0 
    print np.min(foo), np.max(foo)                          # 0.000563234 1.0
    print np.min(goo) - 1e-8, np.max(goo) - 1e-8            # 0.000563224090805 0.99999999
    print np.min(hoo), np.max(hoo)                          # 0.000563234 1.0
```

The `np.inf` error occurs becuase there's a `np.log(1 - x)` operation. Why aren't the values getting scaled? I am unable to subtract a 1e-8 value. How else do people do normalizations?

The scaling works if I use epsilon as `1e-4` but not `1e-8`. Considering that numpy floats are 64bit, why isn't `1e-8` getting computed? I tried replacing `1e-8` with `0.00000001` too, but same error.

Comment: You could take a look at normalisation functions.
The doc is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn)

Look at `softmax` and `sigmoid`. May help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default float precision of TensorFlow is `float32`, whose resolution is `1e-6`. You can check the resolution of type in numpy like this:

```
In [5]: np.finfo(np.float32)
Out[5]: finfo(resolution=1e-06, min=-3.4028235e+38, max=3.4028235e+38, dtype=float32)
```